# MPMoviePlayerController slowmotion

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

Can't change `currentPlaybackRate`... Any value < 0 make playing little slower than normal speed. I want to change playing speed from 1 to 1/2...1/4 and 1/8. But any changes not working. The Player continues playing with own speed(little slower or normal. Even if I set 0.00001 for `currentPlaybackRate` the playing speed not change). So, How to make slow motion effect on MPMoviePlayerController.

```
// Little slower than normal, but same for any value
moviePlayerController.currentPlaybackRate = 0.5;
moviePlayerController.currentPlaybackRate = 0.25;
moviePlayerController.currentPlaybackRate = 0.75;
moviePlayerController.currentPlaybackRate = 0.125;

// Normal
moviePlayerController.currentPlaybackRate = 1;
```

Comment: Rost K. having same issue. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

MPMoviePlayerController is deprecated in iOS 9. You should use AVPlayerViewController instead and use avplayer.Rate property to set the playback rate of the current video.

Comment: If you will wait a couple of years more you may post one more answer like this) June 8, 2015 is release date of iOS 9, Aug 20 2013 is post date! Please read carefully